# German pronounciation of Minuend with Android TTS

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I try to say the word Minuend in German with Android TTS. But my Phone pronounces the ue as a ü (u-Umlaut). Anyone knows a way to force TTS speaking the ue as an ue?

Best Regards, Thomas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was used in ancient times for those typewriters which didn't have the umlauted vowels...

Trick: Try inserting something between the u and the e, like replacing "ue" with "u-e" before reading it.

i.e.:

```
tts.speak(txt,replace("ue", "u-e"), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
```

Where txt is your string ("Minuendo") and tts is the TextToSpeech instance.

It should work, because the TTS engine won't recognize the ue as a diphtong anymore.
And "-" won't be read (or use a comma instead or some other MUTE character).